# TypeScript infering the type while looping over a map

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

The particular TypeScript code receives from the back-end an array of Config type objects.

And for each Config object in the array, it needs to update / populate the params with the appropriate information, and after that do a set of calls, with the populated params.

I am having trouble with creating the appropriate types for this scenario.
Here is some code of the current state of the system, and the problem I encounter.

---

There is an enum with all the available partners:

```js
enum TheEnum {
    Foo = 'foo',
    Bar = 'bar',
}
```

For each partner we know the shape of the params they accept:

```js
interface ParamMap {
    [TheEnum.Foo]: {
        readonly a: number,
        b: string,
        c?: boolean
    },
    [TheEnum.Bar]: {
        z: number,
    },
};
```

We have a map of functions, whose sole purpose is to populate the optional keys, or modify the required ones, that are not readonly:

```js
type ParamGetterFn<T extends TheEnum, U = ParamMap[T]> = (params: U) => U;
type GetterMap = {
    [Key in TheEnum]: ParamGetterFn<Key>;
}
const getterMap: GetterMap = {
    [TheEnum.Foo]: (params) => {
        return { ...params, b: 'adjusted value', c: false };
    },
    [TheEnum.Bar]: (params) => {
        return { ...params, z: 456 };
    },
};
```

The Config object is in the shape of:

```js
interface Config<T extends TheEnum> {
    key: T,
    params: ParamMap[T],
}
```

so the key and the params that come from the back-end need to match.

---

The problem comes when I try to call all of these getters:

```js
function caller(configArr: Config<TheEnum>[]) {
    configArr.map((currentConfig) => {
        const currentGetter = getterMap[currentConfig.key];

        const newParams = currentGetter(currentConfig.params);
        
        // do something with the new / populated params
    })
}
```

I don't quite know how to type this scenario properly, as TypeScript reports:
`Argument of type '{ readonly a: number; b: string; c?: boolean; } | { z: number; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ readonly a: number; b: string; c?: boolean; } & { z: number; }'. Type '{ readonly a: number; b: string; c?: boolean; }' is not assignable to type '{ readonly a: number; b: string; c?: boolean; } & { z: number; }'. Property 'z' is missing in type '{ readonly a: number; b: string; c?: boolean; }' but required in type '{ z: number; }'.`

In my head, because the getters are receiving and returning the same type of object, and the Config type binds the params type and key, TypeScript should figure it out. Clearly I am missing something.

---

I know I am mixing runtime and compile time. And the trouble is that in each iteration `newParams` can be  one of any of the types in ParamMap, but it is depending on the `currentConfig.key`.

I currently just cast it to `any` for it to work:

```js
const newParams = currentGetter(currentConfig.params as any);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can two issues here. The first thing is that your mapping function (the one you pass to `configArr.map`) is non-generic and thus `currentConfig` stands for all possible `TheEnum` values (and in particular, **the value is allowed to be changed**), but in reality, `currentConfig` stands for one particular `TheEnum` value and does not change throughout the mapping function, so what you need is a generic mapping function such as:

```
configArr.map(<T extends TheEnum>(currentConfig: T) => {
    ...
}
```

Secondly, for the moment, TypeScript cannot resolve individual value type based on index signature (expect in the case of tuples), so for `getterMap[currentConfig.key]`, the best thing TypeScript can do is to treat it as the union of all possible value types, even as we apply the generic constraint just mentioned. So unfortunately we still need a little bit of `any` here:

```
configArr.map(<T extends TheEnum>(currentConfig: Config<T>) => {
    const currentGetter: ParamGetterFn<T> = getterMap[currentConfig.key] as any;

    const newParams = currentGetter(currentConfig.params);

    ...
})
```

But once we've done this, you have your `newParams` correctly identified as `ParamMap[T]` and you can continue doing your thing. See this [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAKgFsAouaBvAUFLUBiB7PKAXigHIAzA0gGk2wCEBDAJ2LICMWb0BfddAJYgALsGblGAY2BQACi0YQAsowAOUDNigBteEhQA6fHgC6ALg10tWZsEYATPCAA2ATyiMLKdmNrXs7BYAzsLMQgDmfv5QkgD8FuwEznYgVlA8UVi6CMiQBkzM5pbRUABeXpA+zJnptDwA3PzCrqoy8syKAOLAwqLMOCAAPDBQwAAeoiD2QbA5KAB8bAAUqgoQQRbtiiqquiYAlMSLW8pqe43NrVDdvWI7bJrY2gDSwO5Cs-qQRSc3fQODV6ueaNPjoSROEJQcI9Po7Cx-O5qB5pbJfCBGAhFFZrIKHIiLR7+WzCMDMEAaKAGamrDrrahQQJkBwAKzAIWA9igADdGM4wMAaDELBJnEEZA00hlUXpchiCtjaYo8UditESWSKagqTTcQzylAACwAVgAbOlGlppZLBCIxBJpFAAMJOcgCcLDUYTUDTT5ywlpADWbwsMBqSvWmzWOz2dX45DAIEkwgEThifOSzCWEJAbvCAEFmMwLC7c+7hnNIPNtAc1Vgc3nC8wDBA1EtPeNJr7ZQts2TbCJS3mS67yzB5viAyUc1DJP3QMJEcW5GslwDx2wYbdmDG50WF0P3QZg64TB4ZowQK5GmktDPhFAQMAAO4nGYkPcDxewsR9-eD0dwgMCM8RvEoAHpwKgRwoCCPAIB6OAIigZ8BGEOAoHQmQn2fKAoNUPBVDAZxGFELkQKlfZeCAA).

However, since you still don't know what `T` is in this particular context, there's not much manipulations you can actually perform on `newParams`, except for those properties that are shared by all `ParamMap` subtypes. You either have to convert you object back to `any` (which will make all efforts above meaningless), or use complicated type-guard functions to figure out the exact subtype of `newParams` in order to write any manipulations for individual subtypes.

## Update

One thing TypeScript does not do is discriminating generics (by that, I mean to narrow down the type of generic parameter based on evidences); it only discriminates union types. So in order to utilize this, you have to put things in the form of union types and forget about generics. Of course, your generic definition of `ParamGetterFn` and `GetterMap` helps you to write your `getterMap` instance, so let's keep it that way, but as for the mapping lambda, we need to give up generics:

```
// construct a type that is the union of all possible generic subsitution
type ConfigUnion = {
    [Key in TheEnum]: Config<Key>;
}[TheEnum];

function caller(configArr: Config<TheEnum>[]) {
    configArr.map((currentConfig: Config<TheEnum>) => {
        const currentGetter = getterMap[currentConfig.key] as any;
        const newParams = currentGetter(currentConfig.params) as ConfigUnion;

        // now TypeScript can discriminate the actual type based on its key.

        if (newParams.key == TheEnum.Foo) {
            newParams.params.a // OK
            newParams.params.z // not OK
        }

        if (newParams.key == TheEnum.Bar) {
            newParams.params.z // OK
        }
    })
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAKgFsAouaBvAUFLUBiB7PKAXigHIAzA0gGk2wCEBDAJ2LICMWb0BfddAJYgALsGblGAY2BQACi0YQAsowAOUDNigBteEhQA6fHgC6ALg10tWZsEYATPCAA2ATyiMLKdmNrXs7BYAzsLMQgDmfv5QkgD8FuwEznYgVlA8UVi6CMiQBkzM5pbRUABeXpA+zJnptDwA3PzCrqoy8syKAOLAwqLMOCAAPDBQwAAeoiD2QbA5KAB8bAAUqgoQQRbtiiqquiYAlMSLW8pqe43NrVDdvWI7bJrY2gDSwO5Cs-qQRSc3fQODV6ueaNPjoSROEJQcI9Po7Cx-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-jFXSQRRXV6WZVAuUlHwVr7LwQA)

Comment: Good point with making the mapping lambda generic.
I am curious if this is a limitation of the current state of TypeScript, or if it is impossible to type properly, due to runtime constraints. My intuition says it should be possible.
Of course you are assuming that the data from the back-end is valid.

Comment: I've updated my answer; see if that works better for you.

Comment: I tried something very similar, when typing `function caller(configArr: Config<TheEnum>[]) `. To type it to an array of union types, mapping over all the possible values. But I could not escape the explicit casting inside the mapping function either.
Idealy, I want to type things properly so that type casting is not necessary. Once you resort to that, you might as well not use TypeScript. Except on application boundaries, where the data comes from external services, such as the back-end. There you can enforce as a developer the shape of the data, even if validation might be a better idea.

Comment: Type casting isn't something that you can always avoid, especially as you dig deep enough with advanced typings. There are way too many cases where you simply have more knowledge than what the current version of TypeScript is capable of knowing. And I do not agree with your saying of "might as well not use TypeScript"; what's wrong with occasionally give it a little hand and let it benefits you everywhere else?

Comment: I meant because you are circuventing the type system, you might introduce bugs, and lose some of the benefits. Not using it might be a bit extreme, as TS is useful as a transpiler as well.

Comment: For me even this simpler case is pretty mind bogling:

```typescript
enum TheEnum {
    Foo = 'foo',
    Bar = 'bar',
}

const AppliedMap = {
    [TheEnum.Foo]: { a: 2 },
    [TheEnum.Bar]: { z: '123' },
};

Object.keys(AppliedMap)
    .forEach((key) => {
        const value = AppliedMap[key];
        if (key === TheEnum.Foo) {
            // I assumed that value would be restricted to type { a: number }.
        }
    });
```

I think because Enums can be extended, TS assumes there might be code outside it's knowledge that might change it.